# Xcode 7.2.1 keeps crashing when switching to main.storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, xcode7.2

I can stop it from crashing on startup by manually editing the `main.storyboard` file and changing `useAutoLayout="YES"` to `useAutoLayout="NO"`, but when I open up the `main.storyboard` file in Xcode, it gives me the following error:

```
The document "Main.storyboard" had 4 internal inconsistencies that were found and repaired.
This may be due to an SCM operation such as merging. Please save the document to fix the inconsistencies.
This constraint is not in the referencing constraints for its first item [<Unknown ID>]: object ID K4p-Wa-FrY
This constraint's [object ID 4bY-ZD-KPO] second item is not in the document
This constraint is not in the referencing constraints for its first item [<Unknown ID>]: object ID p48-i6-mG1
This constraint is not in the referencing constraints for its first item [<Unknown ID>]: object ID f2a-1r-b55
```

And when I save it after I hit "OK", Xcode crashes again.

How can I stop it from crashing so I can edit my storyboard?

[Here's](http://pastebin.com/hX1pMnLY) the crash details if that helps.

Comment: They were possibly due to incorrect constraint settings of certain items in your IB. If you don't see any error hints in IB, try removing all constraints from each view until the errors were gone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to open up the `main.storyboard` file with a text editor, and delete all the lines that included the object id's that Xcode was yelling about.